# Designate different connection string within SQL Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Essentially I want to take data from one data source and place it in another.  Unfortunately my software resources are limited and will only allow me to designate one connection string at a time.  I can get around this; however, for time and efficiency purposes I would like to go straight to the other data source in a insert/subselect statement.  Is it possible to change data sources within an SQL query and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Microsoft SQL Server... [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.local_table (list, of, columns)
  SELECT list
       , of
       , columns
  FROM   linked_server.database_name.dbo.not_so_local_table
```

Comment: Thanks! and if the external DB was on my local machine?

Comment: If it's in the same instance of SQL Server and you have adequate permissions with the connected logon to the other database then you can simply use **3-part naming**: `... FROM database_name.schema_name.object_name`

Comment: I believe this will work in production for me; however, for testing purposes to ensure nothing major is going to happen when it goes to the servers is it possible to select from an access database file on the local machine? You've been a tremendous help by the way.

Comment: Try add the Access database as a Linked Server.